# How do you change Material UI Grid properties based on screen size?

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm using Material UI, and I have a grid in the home page. This grid has some properties that I would like to stay regardless on screen size. However, when the screen is `lg` (1200px) or more, I would like to add negative margin.

Currently, the grid looks like

```
<Grid container spacing={0} direction="row" maxWidth="lg" margin="auto">
```

I simply want to add `margin-top="-50px` if the screen size is 1200px or more. What would be the best way to go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to separate your styles from your component or element unless you only want to change one thing or two things.

Try to use useStyles. It will make your life much easier.

To better understand what's going on in here, I've recreated your grid below.

```
import { Grid} from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";

    const YourComponent = () => {
      const classes = useStyles();

      return (
        <>
       <Grid className={classes.myGrid}>
       Your Content Goes Here
      </Grid>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default YourComponent;
```

Material UI has breakpoints implemented supporting multiple screen sizes. Let's say you create another file for your styles, here is what it would look like:

```
      import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
            
            export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
              toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,

              myGrid: {
    
        // here goes your margin for large screens and up
           [theme.breakpoints.up("lg")]: {
          margin: "-50px",
        },
       //here goes your regular size
    }
}));
```

You should be using negative margins with care though. I'm sure there are better ways to recreate your view.

You should definitely take a look at [MUI's documentation on breakpoints](https://mui.com/customization/breakpoints/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [useMediaQuery](https://mui.com/components/use-media-query/) from MUI.

```
const matches = useMediaQuery("(min-width:1200px)");
```

and

```
<Grid
      container
      spacing={0}
      direction="row"
      maxWidth="lg"
      margin={matches ? "-50px auto auto" : "auto"}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be through breakpoints:

```
<Grid container spacing={0} direction="row" maxWidth="lg" margin="auto" sx={{marginTop: {lg: -50px}}}>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).